# Help with C++ Boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to get all words inside a string using Boost::regex in C++.

Here's my input :

"Hello there | network - bla bla        hoho"

using this code :

```
      regex rgx("[a-z]+",boost::regex::perl|boost::regex::icase);

      regex_search(input, result, rgx);

       for(unsigned int j=0; j<result.size(); ++j)
       {
         cout << result[j] << endl;
       }
```

I only get the first word "Hello"..
whats wrong with my code ? result.size() returns 1.

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regex_search only finds the first match. To iterate over all matches, use regex_iterator

Answer (score 1):

Try `rgx("(?:(\\w+)\\W+)+");` as your regex.
(`?:` will start a non-marking group which is finished by the matching `)+` which will match the words in the string 1 or more times
`(\\w+)` will match alpha, digits and underscores 1 or more times as a marked group, i.e. typical word like characters which are returned to you in result[i]
`\\W+` will match one or more contiguous non-word characters, i.e. whitespace, |, - etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're only searching for alphabetic characters, not spaces, pipes or hyphens. `regex_search()` probably just returns the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to capture any set of `[a-z]+` (or some other regex for matching "words") bound by spaces or string boundaries.  You could try something like this:

```
^(\s*.+\s*)+$
```

In any event, this isn't really a boost::regex problem, it's just a regex problem.  use perl or the bash shell (or any number of web tools) to get your regex figured out, then use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using [repeated captures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html#id783181) with the following regex `"(?:([a-z]+)\\b\\s*)+"`.

Answer (score 0):

To match words, try this regex:

```
regex rgx("\\<[a-z]+\\>",boost::regex::perl|boost::regex::icase);
```

According to the docs, `\<` denotes the start of a word and `\>` denotes the end of a word in the Perl variety of Boost regex matching.

I'm afraid someone else has to explain how to iterate the matches. The Boost documentation makes my brain hurt.

Comment: Agreed that the Boost.Regex documentation was fairly bad.